# Парсинг русского языка с веб

Tags: java, android, кодировка

Добрый вечер, произвожу пасрсинг данных на русском языке таким кодом

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}
resultJson = buffer.toString();
```

При этом если установить эту строку в **TextView**, то вместо русских слов будут последовательности  из "�". Попробовал перевести из исходной(**cp1251**) кодировки в **utf-8**, но теперь просто вместо русских слов пробелы. Сам код

```
byte[] arr = resultJson.getBytes("cp1251") ;
Log.d("SMTH", resultJson);
String res = new String(arr, "utf-8");
resultJson = res;
```

Подскажите, как корректно перевести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указать кодировку для InputStreamReader при его создании:

```
new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "windows-1251")
```

Иначе в `resultJson` будет неправильно преобразованное значение с использованием кодировки по умолчанию. Восстановить данные вряд ли уже получится для не ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}
resultJson = buffer.toString();
```